# Is it safe to run XCode project in iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am reviewing an iOS test project by a job candidate. While I don't doubt their best intentions, I'd still like to know what kinds of risks I face when I:

- Open the project in XCode.
- Build the project in XCode ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761082/check-if-number-is-prime-during-compilation-in-c) comes to mind).
- Run the project in the iOS simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Running code from an unknown source (even in a Simulator) is risky.
If you suspect foul play first do a code audit.

Before you do a code audit with XCode however, first make sure the code base does not have any 'XCode modules' in them that might be automatically triggered. The easiest way to do this is to do a rough audit with a plain editor and if all seems ok, open it in XCode.

Use your common sense. Check first, with the least amount of 'helper tools' than slowly after you gain some confidence in the codebase add helper tools to help you in your task.

Comment: Thanks, nice answer. Can you comment on the level of isolation the project in the simulator has from the rest of the system?

Comment: The Simulator mimics the Hardware of the iOS devices. in the past it has been used to develop some of the jailbreaks. Most of those still work. All of the techniques that can exploit the iOS memory model can cause issues on the system running the Sim. Further I have heard unconfirmed rumors of exploits that abuse Apple's Development environment (from some Chinese Developers I know) while I did not find proof. it does seem possible. What I do know is that some chinese developers have had there Development environment polluted with auto-malware adders to there apps (has been in the news).